# How to get only value "Tuýp_2" with sparql query and remove URIRef link "http://www.semanticweb.org/ngocv/ontologies/2020/5/hotrobenhtieuduong#Tuýp_2"

Tags: python, sparql, rdflib, owlready

I'm new to rdflib
I trying to get only the value Tuýp_2, not include the IRI [http://www.semanticweb.org/ngocv/ontologies/2020/5/hotrobenhtieuduong#Tuýp_2](http://www.semanticweb.org/ngocv/ontologies/2020/5/hotrobenhtieuduong#Tu%C3%BDp_2)

```
def testontology():
    test = """PREFIX : <http://www.semanticweb.org/ngocv/ontologies/2020/5/hotrobenhtieuduong#> SELECT ?a   WHERE { <http://www.semanticweb.org/ngocv/ontologies/2020/5/hotrobenhtieuduong#Benhnhan001>:coLoaiTieuDuong ?a}"""
    r = list(graph.query(test))
    for item in r:
        result = str(item['a'])
    return render_template("testontology.html", values=result)
```

The result from the query "test" tried in protege is good [result picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmY5e.png)

when I use `graph.query` it return the value included the iri

I tried with `SELECT (str(?b) as ?a)` as well but the result still the same
I think the problem is I dont know much about get value with `graph.query` in rdflib

Please help me to query the value

Comment: what you want is the local form of a URI. Protege does this in a post processing rendering, but this isn't part of SPARQL itself. It's just a matter of your client code. Indeed, if you know that the namespace is always the same `http://www.semanticweb.org/ngocv/ontologies/2020/5/hotrobenhtieuduong#` - you can simply use the string after it: `bind(strafter(str(?a), "http://www.semanticweb.org/ngocv/ontologies/2020/5/hotrobenhtieuduong#") as ?aTxt)` and use the new variable

Comment: Thanks you so much <3
Now i'm know that i can do more things with [xpath](https://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/#fo-summary)  function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with

```
PREFIX : <http://www.semanticweb.org/ngocv/ontologies/2020/5/hotrobenhtieuduong#> 
SELECT ?aTxt ?a   WHERE { <http://www.semanticweb.org/ngocv/ontologies/2020/5/hotrobenhtieuduong#Benhnhan001>:coLoaiTieuDuong ?a}.
bind(strafter(str(?a),"http://www.semanticweb.org/ngocv/ontologies/2020/5/hotrobenhtieuduong#") as ?aTxt)}
```